# Is Java capable of process monitoring?

Tags: java, monitor

Is it possible to write an application in Java that runs in the tray and when a certain application is launched, it can detect it?  I want to do this for certain programs to find out how long I use them for a weekly basis.  I'm new to Java, so I don't know if Java is even the best language for this, or if it has the proper access to the operating system to do this.

Comment: I was going to say have a look at the Winp library, but the official site seems to be down(https://winp.dev.java.net/). This page has a *little* about it - http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2008/03/introducing_win.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java in itself does not have much integration into system-specific features (nor do most other general-purpose languages).  If you're talking about windows, the system language of choice would be C# (or C/C++).  On Mac, it'd be ObjectiveC (or C/C++).  On linux, it'd be C.

To access process monitoring facilities on a given system, you need to first understand the APIs you're going to be using.  Then you can evaluate whether a given language has built-in or third-party library support for those APIs.

In the case of Java, you'd need to either write some [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/jniTOC.html) (C code), use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/) (Java only), or parse the output of [Runtime.exec()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) (call various system/shell commands) to access the system APIs related to managing and/or monitoring processes.

Comment: You could `for` through the tasklist on windows